# MDX calculated members and set subtraction

Tags: ssas, mdx

Here is a simple example from Adventure Works:

```
with 

member test1 as sum([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]) 
               - [Customer].[Customer].&[28187]

member test2 as sum([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]) 
                - sum([Customer].[Customer].&[28187],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])

member test3 as sum
                (
                    {[Customer].[Customer].children - [Customer].[Customer].&[28187]},
                    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
                ) 

select {test1, test2, test3} on 0
from [Adventure Works]
```

Results are almost equal, except "test1" has non-money type formatting

Questions:

1. "test1" calc-member: How can i subtract "Customer" member expression from numeric result of "sum"? That looks illogical and mind breaking. I expect arithmetic subtraction, set subtraction, but not member from arithmetic subtraction...
2. Are all (test1,test2,test3) calculated members logically and "performantly" equal? If not, what is correct explicit form of "test1" member? It looks like "test2" will perform better in most cases, because "test3" set subtraction may result in very huge set.

Comment: I will give a try to the Except statement http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms144900.aspx

Comment: "Except" is just a shortcut to "test3": [Customer].[Customer].children - [Customer].[Customer].&[28187] is same as Except([Customer].[Customer].children, [Customer].[Customer].&[28187]). "test3" (in any form) works nearly 10 times slower than "test2". "test1" works about 2 times slower than "test2". So "test1" is not a shortcut to any of other members...

Answer (score 2):

"test1" is same as "test2".

Correct explicit form is

```
member test as ([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
                - ([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], [Customer].[Customer].&[28187])
```